# Cocoa: Call App Delegate Method from another Class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsapplication

I'm currently trying to get the path of a file from a drag and drop operation inside of a custom view, and then pass that path to my app delegate. I'm currently using the following:

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender 
{

    NSPasteboard *pb = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    NSString *type = [pb availableTypeFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]];
    NSArray *array = [[pb stringForType:type] propertyList];

    //access the app delegate
    NSApplication *myApplication;
    myApplication = [NSApplication sharedApplication];

    [myApplication uploadFiles:array];

    return NO;

}
```

However, I keep getting a message that says that my app delegate doesn't respond to the "uploadFiles" method. It is declared inside of my app delegate. Am I accessing the NSApplication in the correct manner?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're referring to the application but not its delegate. This should work:

**Mac**

```
[(YourAppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate] uploadFiles:array]
```

replacing YourAppDelegate with your actual app delegate name, and being certain to #import it.

Comment: Shouldn't that be NSApplication?

Comment: @JasperPol Right you are, I was only working on iOS apps back when I answered this 4 years ago. Fixed.