# Binding in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, macos, binding

i am new to stackoverflow, so please be gentle with me.

I am currently working my way into objective-c and mac os x development and i am currently stuck at the simple task of binding a few objects together in a small project i am working on:

I have an object AppDelegate, created from a NIB file, containing a NSMutableArray. I wanted to access that array in another class derived from NSOpenGLView (created from the NIB File as well) to iterate the objects stored in it.

How can this be achieved in Interface Builder?

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: Here is part of my AppDelegate code:

.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {

  IBOutlet NSMutableArray *_players;

}

@property (assign) NSMutableArray *_players;
```

Additionally i have a MyOpenGLView (implementing NSOpenGLView) where i want to access the objects from the `_players` Array.

Comment: WHen you say, "containing a NSMutableArray", what do you mean? Do you mean it has a NSMutableArray as a property? An outlet?

Comment: I updated the question with my current definition of the Array in question. Looks like both (property AND outlet) to me. Can anyone explain me the difference, please?

Comment: An IBOutlet is an interface builder reference while a property is a means of accessing data on an object.  Interface builder can't reference things unless it has some way of accessing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your `NSOpenGLView` have an outlet pointing to your `AppDelegate`?  If not, then you can either make one or use the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363179/cocoa-call-app-delegate-method-from-another-class).

`[(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] uploadFiles:array]`

(This assumes that `AppDelegate` actually refers to *the* application delegate.)

[Apple tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_quick_start/020-Tutorial_Designing_a_User_Interface_with_Interface_Builder/interface_builder_tutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010575-CH3-SW1) on interface builder basics (including connecting outlets).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mydogisbox but we are on Mac OS X here - so i assume you meant `NSApplication` instead of `UIApplication`? Besides, i am looking for a method to connect the array in Interface Builder (and not the appDelegate or the NSOpenGLView). Programmatically your suggestion may work, i will try that out.

Comment: You mean you want something to edit the interface builder file?

Comment: No, not to edit. I want to connect the objects of AppDelegate and MyOpenGLView so that i can access a member of AppDelegate from within MyOpenGLView.

Comment: You can also create outlets between objects in a nib using interface builder just like you would between GUI objects.

Comment: Yep, thats a good description of my goal. Unfortunately, all things i have tried doesn't yield me a result. Do i have to declare the NSMutableArray in both objects? What would be a valid declaration in both interface descriptions, if so?

Comment: If you want to reference the `AppDelegate` in your view, you need an IBOutlet on your view which references your `AppDelegate`.  Then you can just right-click on your `AppDelegate` and draw the reference onto your view and connect the outlet.

Comment: I suggest simply using the code method above, or simply creating a property on your view and using your File's owner reference to your view to pass the array to your view on viewWillLoad or some such.

Comment: Thanks, mydogisbox: I have done the following: i added `IBOutlet AppDelegate *_myAppDelegate;`to MyOpenGLView, and had to drag FROM MyOpenGLView Object in IB TO AppDelegate to set the outlet. Now it works :)